# JavaScript: Send touchscreen tap in game

Tags: javascript, android

I'm making a *JavaScript mod* that I guess you can say is "injected" into an android game. Everything I need to do is working, except for one last thing... I need to send taps on the center of the screen, and I can't find how to do this anywhere!